# Replace only one specified character from string

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I want to replace one character at each iteration from a string.
I already wrote some code that produces the following output:

est

st

t

This is fine and my expected result.

---

But when I add the input:
"hello", my output changes:

ello

llo

o

As you can see, the two "l"'s get removed at the same time. The reason is the following:

"replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence".

As you can see from the documentation, each substring gets replaced. Is there an alternative function in the String class? Note that I only want to use String and no other third party library.

---

Maybe the replace-first function does achieve that? But since it requires regex I don't know how to use it ;(

Thanks for any help in advance!

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String first, String second){

    final int first_len = first.length();
    final int second_len = second.length();
    if (first_len != second_len){
        return false;
    }

    //String newWord = oldWord.replace(oldChar,newChar)

    for (int i = 0; i < first_len; i++) {
        char ch = first.charAt(i);
        first = first.replace(ch, ' ');
        System.out.println(first);
        for (int j = 0; j < first_len; j++){
            if (second.charAt(j) == ch) {
                second = second.replace(second.charAt(j), ' ');
            }
        }
    }

    if (first.trim().isEmpty() && second.trim().isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you looked at the Documentation of String? You might have spotted that the String class has a method called `replaceFirst`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) - Apart from that the examples you have provided look to me like replacing isn't even needed at all. Simply using `substring(1)` as long as the String is not empty should siffice. (eG: `"Hello".subString(1);` will return `"ello"`, `"ello".substring(1)` will return `"llo"` etc. pp )

Comment: `I already wrote some code that produces the following output` . Where is the code?

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder instead of trying to manipulate the String yourself.

Comment: @vsfDawg No I am disallowed to use a StringBuilder for that task. But thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Well yeah. Using substring(1) works fine for the first three iterations. But then I get an error: String index out of range: 3

Comment: @Eldinur I just posted an answer that shows how your idea with fixed code would work with using replaceFirst. You basically made it way to complicated by needlessly introducing a second nested loop and also replacing / modifying both Strings instead of just the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using `"Hello".substring(1);` will remove the first letter in a consistent manner

Comment: Thanks, but how would I implement that? I added the code snippet above now.

Answer (score 1):

While I do think there are better ways to check if a String is an anagram, I think it might be helpful if you see how your idea implemented correctly would look like.

Your method was needlessly complicated.
All you really need to do is:

1. Iterate over the chars of your first String
2. replace the first occurrence of that char in the second string with an empty String.
3. After you are done iterating check if the second String is now empty, which will tell you if all chars from the first String where found:

--

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String first, String second) {

    final int first_len = first.length();
    final int second_len = second.length();
    if (first_len != second_len) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // If you want your anagram check to be case sensitive, comment out the following 2 lines
    first = first.toLowerCase();
    second = second.toLowerCase();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < first_len; i++) {
        final char ch = first.charAt(i);
        second = second.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(ch)), "");
    }

    if (second.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because the `replaceFirst` method uses regular expressions as an argument we use the method `Pattern.quote` to make sure the passed character gets interpreted as a literal character and not accidentally as some special regular expression character.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great! But I am disallowed to rely on outer classes like "Pattern" That's also why I used this approach

Comment: It's a standard java class no different than String. You can also remove that and just use `replaceFirst(String.valueOf(ch), "")`. This would however make problems for some edge cases where your String contains a character that has a special meaning in regular expression. For example if your Strings would contain a `.` dot, because in regex that dot not being escaped means "any character" so it would just replace any character it finds.